# Using the Vertx mongodb client fluently vs inline vs nested

Tags: java, mongodb, vert.x

Read through the docs and i'm still confused as the the advantages (if any) of using the mongoClient in a fluent way. Can anyone explain them to to me and if it will guarantee order;

**Running in line - Both will be run at the same time with no guarentee of order.**

```
mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getSomeCommand1(), res -> {});
mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getSomeCommand2(), res -> {});
```

**Running nested - getSomeCommand1 will be run to completion first before getSomeCommand2.**

```
mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getSomeCommand1(), res1 -> {
       mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getSomeCommand2(), res2 -> {});
});
```

**Running in a fluent way - is the same as running in line?**

```
mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getSomeCommand1(), res -> {}).mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getSomeCommand2(), res -> {});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far from a complete answer but running a few basic tests indicates that running in a fluent way is the same as running in line;

I ran a slow command (aggregate) and a fast command (count) on a large dataset.

```
mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getTotalRecsPerTypeCommand(sellerId, collection), res -> {
    result.put("totalRecsPerType", res.result());
}).count(collection, new JsonObject().put("sellerId", sellerId), res -> {
    result.put("totalRecs", res.result());
    requestMessage.reply(result);
});
```

Initially only the total is returned however when the reply is moved from the fast command to the slow command then both results are returned. This indicates they are both run at the same time with no guarentee of order.

```
    mongoClient.runCommand("aggregate", getTotalRecsPerTypeCommand(sellerId, collection), res -> {
        result.put("totalRecsPerType", res.result());
        requestMessage.reply(result);
    }).count(collection, new JsonObject().put("sellerId", sellerId), res -> {
        result.put("totalRecs", res.result());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Running in line does **not** guarantee the order of execution, that is maybe running the first code several times on not heavily loaded machine will preserve order.

The same thing is with fluent API. In this case it only helps you to omit semicolon. If you want to create a *flow*, where the next command will be fired after the first one ends, use RxJava (or the nested case, but in the long run you might end up with [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)).

Take a look here: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client/blob/master/vertx-mongo-service/src/main/generated/io/vertx/rxjava/ext/mongo/MongoService.java
Although I'm not a big fan of `ObservableFuture` used in this class (I recommend using http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/AsyncSubject.html), it's a good starting point.